# Sencha's body background get drawn on top of my canvas

Tags: canvas, sencha-touch

I'm drawing on a canvas, and when I debug I can see that I get the things done, but then the sencha body background gets drawn on top of it.

My html is:

```
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

and I have some javascript that draws the things I need.

So I draw inside the canvas, but the html code that is generated has the following which is drawn on top of my canvas:

```
<body id="ext-gen1003" class=" x-desktop" style="width: 879px; height: 386px; ">
```

If I comment the sencha.css I don't have the problem anymore, but more things disappear with that, so obvoiusly that is not a solution
What can I do to get the canvas on top of the background?

EDIT: A solution I found was to create the tag manually and adding it to the document:

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id = "canvas";
canvas.innerHTML = "myCanvas";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

but I believe there must be a more elegant solution, besides, here I need to add something in the innerHTML or else I don't get the closing tag: .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to add an Ext.Panel and set the html property to the html code you want to add.  For example:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({  html: '<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>' });
```

Then add panel to whatever your main container is.

Comment: I just tried that and it draws the canvas with 0 height, I tried setting the height manually with height: "100%" and height:"310", but i get width: 1280 and heigh: 0. I have tried adding this panel to the items of my main panel and as a dockedItem, neither one works. Any idea on how to set the height? thanks

Comment: Try setting the height on the panel config object (the thing you pass into the constructor)  Also try setting fullscreen : true or layout : 'fit'

Comment: Set the height in pixels: <canvas id="canvas" height="200px"></canvas>